# Failed to pull image - Azure AKS

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application?tabs=azure-cli) to deploy application on Azure using AKS

Every thing was fine until I deployed, one node is in `not ready` state with `ImagePullBackOff` status

[kubectl describe pod output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwpR8.png)

Performing below command I get success command, so I am sure authentication is happening

```
az acr login --name siddacr
```

and this command lists out the image which was uploaded

```
az acr repository list --name <acrName> --output table
```

Comment: Did you add your cluster's managed service identity to the `AcrPull` role on the ACR?

Comment: As Daniel mentioned, AKS works with 2 Service principals. You need to have the cluster service principal as a service connection in Azure DevOps. Using this in the task, instead of Azure Service principal AKS actions can be invoked. 

On the ACR side, make sure [it is attached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli#configure-acr-integration-for-existing-aks-clusters) properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out.

The error was in the name of the image in deployment.yml file

Answer (score 0):

`imagebackpulloff` might be caused because of the following reasons:

- The image or tag doesn’t exist
- You’ve made a typo in the image name or tag
- The image registry requires authentication
- You’ve exceeded a rate or download limit on the registry